# Selenium: Unable to use any locators

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I've tried many possible locators but selenium webdriver doesn't recognize any. I've used the firebug/firefinder, inspect element and even tested the unique locators returned with Selenium IDE. however when i use it in the webdriver script, I get an error "The given selector is .. either invalid or does not result in a Webelement"

I need to select the Preview button.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Preview</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
By byXPath = By.XPath("//span[.=='Preview']");
//use "div>button:first-child" if you want to use CssSelector

Driver.FindElement(byXPath).Click();
```

if this does not work you are doing something wrong inside your code. I am using C#

Comment: The Cssselector worked but only partially. Now the Preview button gets highlighted (as in set focus) but it doesn't get clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Preview']")).Click();`